# Couchbase Java API not returning values for set range

Tags: java, couchbase

I'm having a weird problem with Couchbase Java API. I use the following code:

```
ViewQuery query = ViewQuery.from(BUCKET_NAME, GET_ENTITIES_VIEW_NAME);
... 
// set companyStart, companyEnd as Strings
// set query.limit and query.skip
...
query.startKey(toJsonArray(companyStart, Long.toString(params.getStartDate().getTime())));
        endKey(toJsonArray(companyEnd, Long.toString(params.getEndDate().getTime())));
ViewResult results;
results = bucket.query(query);
...
```

When I try the said start and endKeys (like ["ROTOR", 146538100000]) in the Couchbase console, the query returns all the expected results.

However, with the Java API the results is empty.

If I comment out the query.startKey and .endKey lines, it faithfully returns all the results for the view.

Here's my view:

```
function (doc, meta) {
  if(doc.collectorData.documenttypes.terms[0] && doc.collectorData.documenttypes.terms[0]=='EAP:Article') {
    emit([doc.collectorData.userdata.company,doc.timestamp], {"visitId":doc.visitId,"visitorId":doc.visitorId,"company":doc.collectorData.userdata.company,"timestamp":doc.timestamp, "userAgent":doc.userAgent, "pathInfo":doc.pathInfo, "channel":doc.collectorData.channel, "newVisit":doc.newVisit});
   }
}
```

Any tips on what may be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `Long.toString`, so it is not equivalent to what you used in the couchbase console.
That would be equivalent to `["ROTOR", "146538100000"]`. A subtle but meaningful difference!

Try with the following snippet instead (I explicitly used `JsonArray.from` as well, just to remove any ambiguity):

```
query
    .startKey(JsonArray.from(companyStart, params.getStartDate().getTime()))
    .endKey(JsonArray.from(companyEnd, params.getEndDate().getTime()));
```

Comment: That is a fantastic answer and is very helpful indeed. The new code gives me ["",1433113200000] and ["zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz",1465391306430] for start and end keys correspondingly (that is after decoding a sequence like "%5B%22%22%2C1433113200000%5D" for the start day, which I've extracted from IntelliJ's debugger for the startKey). Both these values, tried in Couchbase console, work out of the box. Sadly, it still does not work from Java - the result set is empty. I even tried query.startKey(JsonArray.from("[\"\",1433113200000]"), but that still does not work. What else can I try?

Comment: on the `ViewResult`, what do the `success()` and `error()` methods return? you can also try to activate `debug()` on the `ViewQuery`, then access that information on the `ViewResult` via the `debug()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Simon's tips were most helpful. The mystery had a simple solution: I forgot to publish the view, and the old view only had one-field key, so the query was executing successfully yet returning nothing! A comment somewhere through the thread on https://forums.couchbase.com/t/not-able-to-get-all-rows-returned-from-couchbase-view/5020/23 provided the enlightenment.

Comment: ah that was my next suggestion if `error()` showed nothing :)